# Asp.net mvc Role based and Rule based operations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, authorization

I am a bit confused about role and rule with my application. My some **users** will be **authorized** edit data on my web site. For example I will create roles like this:

- EDITOR
- ADMIN
- VIEWER

Asp.net mvc has an attribute named Authorize. I can specify roles for **controller** and **actions** .

```
    [Authorize]
    public class GeometryController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize(Roles = "VIEWER")]
        public ActionResult Get(string id)
        {
            return Content("OK.");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN, EDITOR")]
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {           
           return Content("This operation is restricted for you.");   
        }
    }
```

But I have another role that some users can edit data by working area. For example

- **user1** can only edit Arizona data and view All zone data.
- **user2** can edit and delete Texas data.

Comment: Just extend the default `Authorize` attribute and include your logic

Answer (score 1):

I've done something close to the following in my code.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _feature;
        private readonly string _permission;

        public BRTAuthorizeAttribute( string feature, string permission)
        {
            _feature = feature;
            _permission = permission;
        }

        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (!base.IsAuthorized(actionContext))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if(// check access rights)
            {
                return true
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then decorate controllers with `[CustomAuthorize("feature", "permission")]` this should be what you need.